# regex question with partial solution already found

Tags: python-3.x

```
string = "My QUIZZING codes is GREATLY bad so quizzing number is the integer 94.4; I don't like any other BuzzcuT except 1.\n"
```

From this string of gibberish, I want to pull out the words QUIZZING GREATLY and BuzzcuT leaving their capitalization's or lack thereof as is.

```
caps = re.findall('([A-Z]+(?:(?!\s?[A-Z][a-z])\s?[A-Z])+)', string)
print(string)
```

This code that  I have/the code that you see results in  `['QUIZZING', 'GREATLY']`....but I am hoping to get  `['QUIZZING', 'GREATLY', 'BuzzcuT']`
Although it's gibberish, the point is the various alpha/numeric combinations that make it a challenge .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex below finds the 3 patterns in your example string.

```
import re

string = "My QUIZZING codes is GREATLY bad so quizzing number is the integer 94.4; I don't like any other BuzzcuT except 1.\n"


# The regex contains 2 patterns
# \b[A-Z]{3,}\S*\b -- will match QUIZZING and GREATLY
# \b[A-Z]{1}[a-z]\S*[A-Z]\b -- will match BuzzcuT
#
# You could use a single pattern -- [A-Z]{1,}\S*[A-Z] 
# to match all 3 words
# 
word_pattern = re.compile(r'\b[A-Z]{3,}\S*\b|\b[A-Z]{1}[a-z]\S*[A-Z]\b')
find_words = re.findall(word_pattern, string)
if find_words:
  print (find_words)
  # output 
  ['QUIZZING', 'GREATLY', 'BuzzcuT']
```